# Make ChatBubbleTextBox (TextBox) content scrollable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, windows-phone

I'm developing simple chat WP application. I use ChatBubble text block control from Coding4Fun toolkit. I want to make this contoll scrollable when user is holding finger on it and moving to up/down. I changed control style by placing ContentControl inside ScrollViewer contol but didn't help. It's just "responsible" now but I still can't scroll inside it.

```
<Border x:Name="EnabledBorder" 
    Grid.Row="1"
    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl
            x:Name="HintContentElement"
            BorderThickness="0" 
            Background="Transparent"
            Foreground="Gray"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            Content="{TemplateBinding Hint}" />
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ContentControl 
                    x:Name="ContentElement" 
                    Margin="1 2"
                    MaxHeight="170"
                    BorderThickness="0" 
                    Background="Transparent"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
            </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Here is piece of page XAML

```
<c4f:ChatBubbleTextBox 
    InputScope="Text" 
    TextChanged="ChatBubbleTextBox_TextChanged" 
    Text="{Binding CommentText, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ChatBubbleDirection="LowerRight" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    Style="{StaticResource themeAwareChatBubbleStyle}" />
```

Comment: Try Background="Transparent" on your ScrollViewer so not just the content acts as the hit spot to scroll

Comment: @ChrisW. same result. I guess ScrollViewer has transparent bg by default.

Comment: Ya I was thinking maybe it was like silverlight where you have to do that sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

to fix that issue:
replace

```
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ContentControl 
                x:Name="ContentElement" 
                Margin="1 2"
                MaxHeight="170"
                BorderThickness="0" 
                Background="Transparent"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
        </ScrollViewer>
```

with

```
        <ScrollViewer
                x:Name="ContentElement" 
                Margin="1 2"
                MaxHeight="170"
                BorderThickness="0" 
                Background="Transparent"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```